# Create a map from a list (collection)

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a class with different attributes. A list contains object from this class. Some objects have the same name (attribute). I now want to create a map where the key is the name and the value is the actual object.

```
Map<String, Order> splittedListMap = listOfOrder.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Order::getDriver, 
        Order::getOrder));
```

I get the following message when compiling:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key Mike Miller (attempted merging values ​​com.xxxxxxxxxxxx"

How do I do this without this exception?

Comment: Seems like you have multiple `Order`s with the same `driver`-value, hence we have a key collision.

Comment: We can deal with this by providing a merge function (see [here (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)). But we need to know how to deal with this. One common approach would be to have a `Map<String, List<Order>>`, so we can support muptliple `Order`-entries per key.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but I have to wonder if this implies there is room for improvement in the basic design.

Answer (score 0):

Maps cannot have duplicate keys so if you encounter them you need to group the values under the same key.  Here is one way to do that.

```
Map<String, List<Order>> splittedListMap = listOfOrder.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getDriver);
```

All the drivers with the same name will be in the list of Order.

If you want have a `Map<String, Order>` then String should be a unique value for each driver.  It could be an id of some sort.  Then you can do it as you first attempted.

**Note:**  `Order::getOrder` doesn't make sense as you want the value to be an `Order` type which is also the class itself.  So it looks like `getOrder` simply returns itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Can you tell me how I can do the getOrder differently? I actually need the driver from the object as a key and the object again as a value...

Comment: You really don't need a `getOrder` method in the `Order` class.  Think about it.  To be able to invoke `getOrder` you need the instance of the class.  Which means you already have what you are trying to get.  In your previous example, for `Map<String, Order>` you could have done `Map<String, Order> splittedListMap = listOfOrder.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Order::getDriver,  o -> o);` where `o` is the streamed object and simply says, use that. Of course, the duplicate key situation is still present.  `Function.identity()` is the more expressive equivalent of `o->o` and can also be used.

Comment: @bz94  Did that last explanation help your at all?